# Iterating with .each through jQuery ajax json is not working in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer, each

I'm using the following code to create divs with "random" products. The JSON data received from PHP is like this:

```
{"New":[{"product_id":"50",...},...],
"Best":[{"product_id":"26",...},...],
...}
```

"New" products must go to `<div id="New">`, "Best" to "Best" and so on.

Code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/index.php?AjaxRequest&action=5",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown + '\n' + status + '\n' + xhr.statusText);
    },

    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            var new_str = '<ul>';
            $(value.sort(function () {
                return 0.5 - Math.random()
            }).slice(0, 3)).each(function () {
                new_str += '<li><a href="' + this.link + '" class="right_sidebar">';
                new_str += '<img class="right_sidebar_thumb" src="' + this.image + '" alt="' + this.name + '"/></a></li>';
            });
            new_str += '</ul>';
            $('#' + key).append(new_str);
        });
    }
});
```

The problem arises only with IE. It iterates only the first time, and fills only the first div, while all other browsers work fine.

The problem is not in duplicate div ids, and JSON is valid, and jQuery gives no errors.

Comment: Sorting with a random function like that is not a super-good idea, as you really have no idea how long it'll take to do it, and it won't be a good shuffle anyway.

Comment: Which .each isn't repeating, the outer one or the inner one ?

Comment: the outer one goes only the first time in IE

Comment: Then what is a better way to shuffle?

Comment: Cat and mouse I'm afraid, I suggest that In the IE developer toolbar, put a Javascript breakpoint on the first $.each after the success method; then have a look and see what data actually appears like in your watch window.

Comment: Better way to shuffle them would be to have PHP return the last in a random order I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is now resolved!
Needed to turn caching to off: `cache:false` !
Thanks to everybody!